# Como puedo obtener la siguiente salida con bitset en C++?

Tags: c++

Como pudiera imprimir el bitset en C++?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    bitset <32> B;
    int k=5;
    
    B=5;

    cout<< B << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

La salida que necesito es  101, pero la que obtengo es 00000000000000000000000000000101.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la función [string::find_first_not_of()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/) para obtener la posición del primer carácter que no sea un cero. Luego usas [string::erase()](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) para borrar desde el principio de la cadena (índice 0) hasta la posición del primer carácter que no sea un cero.

```
    int k = 5;
    string binario = bitset<32>(k).to_string();
    binario.erase(0, binario.find_first_not_of('0'));
    cout << binario << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

El objetivo del `std::bitset` es la gestión de bits, precisamente por eso en el momento de mostrarlo los muestra todos. Si quieres una representación numérica puedes llamar a la función que devuelve el valor numérico [`std::bitset::to_ulong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong) y lo imprimes en binario:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <charconv>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    constexpr int size = 32;
    bitset <size> B;
    B = 5;

    char bin[size]{};
    std::to_chars(bin, bin + size, B.to_ulong(), 2);
    cout << bin << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NCoJQEIXXzlMMtFGyiKJNmgtfIyJu18Eu6Cj3J6Lo2W2uLWo1cL4z39HjuNKd4naaFoZ1FxrC0gzOW1J9Bb/sarwj/5/om7J64HsFYNhjrwynGbwgCc5wi6x6cqPShM43BUAiXefpMVqMdWeehEfcbQtIvm4sY1ZhLUktaD8/yQheDZ8iO7/ewkR3OPjhEpFLheWxgMtZmWO9Fha6gds0y3GbFXE5iL2ca3KImy66LflgGTcFvKfpAw)</kbd>.